# Synchronized audio playback on separate Android devices

Tags: android, synchronization, audio-streaming

I'm curious how I would play the same audio on multiple android devices all in sync? [seedio](http://www.theverge.com/2012/8/2/3214678/seedio-ios-music-sync-loudspeaker-app) for iOS is an example of what I'm talking about.

I can think of two possible scenarios. Cache the audio on each device and exactly synchronize playback start time. Use an RTP like protocol to synchronize the playback in real-time.

Comment: **Exact** synchronization isn't possible, due to minor variations in clock rate.  How synchronized does this have to be for your application?

Comment: Just enough that it it's not noticeable to someone using two devices on either side of a room to listen to music.

Comment: Has anyone made any progress on this question? I'm very interested.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to cache the audio an every device and then synchronize the playback.

NTP can get you surprisingly good clock synchronization.

Then maybe you redo the clock sync ever so often and restart playback from a common point in the file after to account for drift in clock speeds. How often you need this will vary based on how much clock drift there is on the devices.

An interesting research project.